# "Variable does not exist" error in catch block even when the variable is outside the try block

Tags: batch, compile-error, try-catch

I have written a batch class and using try-catch in its execute method. But on saving the class, getting variable does not exist error. Sample code is given below:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> accList) {
   try{
      //some code here
   }catch(Exception e){
       for(Account acc: accList){
           acc.Status__c = 'FAILED';
       }
       update accList; 
   }
}
```

Getting error "Variable does not exist: Status__c". Any help here would be appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error happens if your org has class name as Account.

Otherwise, you may need to enable the Field level security for Status field on Account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But there is no class in the org with class name as Account. Also, same field is being referred in try block as well for which it is not giving any error. It is happening only in the batch context, for any other normal method, it is working fine.

Comment: Could you update your question with minimal version of code illustrating the problem?